# Running unit test of a module that imports another module in parent directory failed

Tags: python, unit-testing, import

The project structure is as follows:

```
/root
- /crawler
 - /basic
   - agent.py
 - settings.py
 - main.py
- /tests
 - /basic
   - test_agent.py
 - test_main.py
```

`main.py` imports `agent.py`, and `agent.py` imports `settings.py`. It works fine because we run `main.py` under `/root/crawler`, making the interpreter add `/root/crawler` (because it's where `main.py` lives) to sys.path, so when `agent.py` is imported and interpreted, `import settings` raises no exceptions.

However, when running unit tests using *nose* under `/root`, all other tests are OK except `test_agent.py`, the interpretor reported that it didn't know where to import `settings`.

It would work if I appended `/root/crawl` to the path inside `test_agent.py` before importing the module being tested, but that would be considered as a bad practice, right?

If so how to avoid the `ImportError`?

Comment: Whoever voted to close - that was a terrible decision. This is a legitimate problem OP is having, and has provided all the information they could have.

Comment: OP, are you using python 2.x or python 3.x?

Comment: I'm using python 2.7.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `settings` must be a top level module, then it is fine to add `/root/crawl` to `sys.path` from within your test files. If you think that `crawl` itself might be importable elsewhere and used like a library from another program, then you should consider restructuring your packages.

You might want to do something like this:

```
/root $ tree
.
├── crawler
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── basic
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── agent.py
│   └── settings.py
├── main.py
├── test_main.py
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    └── crawler
        ├── __init__.py
        └── basic
            ├── __init__.py
            └── test_agent.py
```

From main you would do:

```
from crawler.basic import agent
agent.do_work()
```

And from agent you would import settings like so:

```
from crawler import settings # or: from .. import settings
print settings.my_setting
```

test_main.py:

```
from tests.crawler.basic import test_agent¬
print 'in test_main'
```

test_agent.py:

```
from crawler.basic import agent
```

And everything works like it's supposed to. The trick is creating the folder structure like  a library, as a package, and having your entry point into your program outside that structure and importing the package.

You could also move your tests directory into the crawler directory, and run `crawler.tests.basic.test_agent`.